# jquery autocomplete for select control (dropdown) in asp.net page with master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have an issue with jquery autocomplete feature in a .aspx (web forms) page which has master page as a parent. 
In a normal aspx page I am able to render the dropdown as I want with autocomplete feature, but when I am doing the same thing in a child page under master page only normal dropdown appears. 
So this is what I have. 
This one looks ok when is rendered and it works ok (normal aspx page without master page):

```
 <select name="select" runat="server" id="select2" class="nostyle" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select state">
<option></option>`                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</select>
```

This one, as part of child page within master page doesn't work the same:

```
  <select name="select2" runat="server" id="select2" class="nostyle" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select state">
                                                               <option></option>                                                           
                                                               <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                               <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>                                                                                               
   <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>                                                              
    </select>
```

The JS for the autocomplete can be found at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/JjVHU/

My question is why the dropdown autocomplete feature is working on the page without master page, and the one with master page is not working although all the js files are connected correctly.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: You might find someone to debug that huge JS source in your fiddle, but it won't be me. - and why not just use the jQuery UI version?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss jquery UI for some reason is not compatible with the twitter bootstrap theme I am using for this project. What I found is that the id of the dropdown is changing when some control is in child page within master page and that's what I am investigating now, thx for your comment

Comment: hmm interesting, what if you use a class to hook to and not the id?

Comment: how can I do that? because everywhere in the js files I can see select2 is used. Thx for help